# When executing python script, How to find username from which sudo is executed?

Tags: python, operating-system, chown

I'm writing a code which will be running on different machines.
Inside code, log file need to be created as **"/tmp/2019-05-02/log_file"** ie, creating a sub directory for each day then creating log file inside the new folder. For this reason to make directory inside "/tmp" directory I need to run my code as

```
sudo python /path/to/code.py
```

Later in the same code I need to create another directory for each day inside **"Documents"**. owner of this newly created directory is root since my code is running as sudo. 
The real problem comes into scene when I want to delete this newly created sub directory inside Documents from the UI application :Files.

So what I did is changed directory permission. So that I can delete this folder with out any trouble.

```
os.chmod("/path/to/directory/inside/Documents", 0747)
```

But now now when I **ls** inside Documents. These newly created folder is showing as Blue text with green background |indicates that a directory is writable by others apart from the owning user and group, and does not have the sticky bit set (o+w, -t).

Is there any way such that the owner of folder created inside /tmp/2019-05-2 is root and the folder created inside Documents is owned by normal user (from that user I executed the program as sudo).

In my machine the user is **dell**. I can change owner using chown in my machine since I know my user name. But I need to change owner even if the code is executing on different machine with different usernames.

Comment: See the examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/1081/os.setuid) They show how a setuid script can return to the original user's ID.

Comment: Try it: print(os.getenv("SUDO_USER"))

Comment: I think you don't need to run sudo to make directory in /tmp.

Comment: @kantal print(os.getenv("SUDO_USER")) it works. Thanks. i run sudo since i was using os.makedirs() to create more than one direectory under /tmp as in /tmp/1/2/3 like this.

Comment: @kantal os.getenv("SUDO_USER") returns none when i run as non sudo. os.getlogin() return login name associated no matter what.

Comment: `import pwd` then 'pwd.getpwnam('someuser')[0]` and `os.getlogin()` returns correct result when using sudo and su

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the most reliable way is to use `os.getlogin()`. It returns the login name associated to the *session* and can only be changed by a `setlogin` system call, which is seldom used in normal programs ([ref.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin)).

The Python manual says:

> For most purposes, it is more useful to use the environment variables LOGNAME or USERNAME to find out who the user is...

But the unix man pages explain the rationale behind:

> ... This is more flexible precisely because the user can set LOGNAME arbitrarily.

Comment: What if user has used `su` instead of `sudo`?

Comment: os.getlogin() returns intended result in that case also.